# How to update the stock that already exists in the table

Tags: eloquent

I have two tables in my database that I have created through migration say products and product_variations and the corresponding model is Product and ProductVariation.
In products table I have three columns say id,name and price and in product_variations table I have the variations of the product that have id,variation,stock and one foreign key(Product_id) column references to the id column of the products table. now I want to display a table in such a way that it will mention the product,price ,variation and stock and also the logic is that If a product laready exist in the table it will skip and new products will be added and similarly it will scan the variations table .If a variation not exist it will add and at the same time if a variation already exist it will update the stock and also for a new variation the lowest price will be saved.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the ER diagram which will be help the readers to understand your question better. Please mention which DB you are using.

Comment: Do you want to create a resultant table? or just want to display the result ?